# Which key is in use when ssh logging into my EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

After a ssh-keyscan I opened my generated known_hosts file, and found that there are 3 instead of 1 key for my EC2 instance.

```
**.**.**.** ssh-rsa ******
**.**.**.** ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 ***
**.**.**.** ssh-ed25519 ***
```

Are they all being used when logging in? Can I safely delete from them if some are not used at all?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes but it's highly related to programming and very very specific, can it be forgiven?

Comment: Sorry, but it's not related to programming at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `ssh-keygen -H  -F <your EC2 URI>`, it'll tell you which line(s) is/are being used.

E.g. `# Host <whatever>.amazonaws.com found: line 15`

If it's not used, you can delete it. Even if you delete one that's used, it'll just ask you to confirm that it's okay next time you connect.

Comment: Thanks, should this line be run on the remote server or the local machine/

Comment: Local machine :)

Comment: Yes that works! Thank you! How come it gave me three when I only asked for one?

Comment: I'm not super versed in ssh, but I'm pretty sure  you can have multiple entries for a connection.